# Detectar Quebra de Linha

Tags: javascript, string, regex

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
  if (str.match(/\d\d\d\d\d\.\d\d\d\d\d/)) {
    var codigo_velho = str.match(/\d\d\d\d\d\.\d\d\d\d\d\/);
    result = "1"; }
```

Como alterar esta função para que ela detecte quebra de linha no `match`? Por exemplo, tentei com `\n` mas não deu certo:

```
 if (str.match(/\d\d\d\d\d\.
                         \d\d\d\d\d/)) {
    var codigo_velho = str.match(/\d\d\d\d\d\.
                                       \d\d\d\d\d\/);
    result = "1"; }
```

Comment: Ja testou com a expressão \n dentro da regex? Tipo: \d\d\n\d...? Sei que quebrar a linha não funciona.

Comment: Tentou `\r\n`? Quebra de linha é meio variável...

Comment: @FelipeAvelar, tentei \r\n não deu certo..

Comment: @Wakim, infelizmente não deu. Porque a linha de códigos que vem no MATCH, algumas delas pulam  linha. tipo 222222\n222222, quando acontece isso ele não detecta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A pergunta já foi amplamente respondida, então apenas farei uma sugestão, ao invés de utilizar [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) para detectar quebras de linha, use [`.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) para verificar se o conteúdo a testar contem ou não quebras de linha, algo assim:

```js
verificarQuebra = function()
{
  var valor = $('#div1').html();
  if (/[\n|\n\r]/.test(valor))  
  {
      alert("Existem quebras de linha!");
  } else
  {
      alert("Não existem quebras de linha!");
  } 
}
```

Demonstração [`aqui`](http://jsfiddle.net/ETHjL/).

---

Existe diferença entre [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) e [`.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)?

A função [`.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) Faz a busca entre uma expressão regular e uma *string* especificada. Retorna *true* ou *false*. Já [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) é utilizado para obter os resultados ao combinar uma *string* contra uma expressão regular. Retorna uma *array* com os resultados ou nulo se não há nenhum. Logo `null == false` se a string não tem um resultado, o valor booleano será *false*.

O [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) cita o seguinte sobre:

> Se você precisa saber se uma string corresponde a uma expressão
>   regular, use RegExp.test(str).

Em relação a performance existe uma diferença significativa? Segundo o [JsPerf](http://jsperf.com/test-vs-match-regex), sim, a diferença é de aproximadamente *30% ~ 60%* dependendo do navegador. Detalhes retirado [`dessa resposta`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10940138/1608936).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bela resposta amigo @DBX8!

Answer (score 10):

Não use quebras de linha literais, use `\n` e uma salvaguarda para o `\r`: `\r?\n`. Assim funcionaria com quebras de linha estilo Unix (`\n`) e Windows (`\r\n`). A parte do `match` então ficaria assim:

```
str.match(/\d\d\d\d\d\.\r?\n\d\d\d\d\d/)
```

Ou encurtando um pouco com a [sugestão do Leonardo Bosquett](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17073):

```
str.match(/\d{5}\.\r?\n\d{5}/)
```

Comment: Qual o motivo de usar a flag multiline neste caso? Até onde lembro, a flag `m` altera o comportamento das âncoras `^` e `$` para match'ar no início e fim de cada linha invés do início e fim da string. Como você não está utilizando estas âncoras, esta flag não deve fazer diferença alguma.

Comment: Você tem razão @FabrícioMatté. Vou excluir a resposta, já que sem isso as outras já dizem tudo o que precisa ser dito.

Comment: Bom, eu não a excluiria, o seu `\r?\n` não está mencionado em nenhuma outra resposta, e também é a minha forma favorita de match'ar quebras de linhas. `=]`

Comment: Acatado @FabrícioMatté :) Editei.

Answer (score 5):

A quebra de linhas pode ter formatos diferentes. A melhor maneira de as "apanhar" é ser abrangente na regex.

Sugestão: `string.match(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm);`

O seletor `\n` é o essencial. Vale a pena ler [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1761086/2256325) sobre diferenças entre `\n` e `\r`. Depois usei o `g` para me retornar todos os resultados, e não somente o promeiro, e ainda o `m` que quer dizer *multiplas-linhas*. No exemplo que coloco em baixo não é necessário mas como não sei exatamente como vai usar, coloquei.

Exemplo em funcionamento: http://jsfiddle.net/yL5Gk/

HTML

```
<div id="div1">Quebra de linha 1: 
    - continua aqui</div>
<div id="div2">Quebra. <br />Quebra. 





    Quebrão :)</div>
<div id="div3">Nenhuma quebra</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var mensagem = '';
$('div').each(function () {
    var string = this.innerHTML;
    var linhas = string.match(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm);
    var quantidadeLinhas = linhas ? linhas.length : 0;
    mensagem += 'A div ' + this.id + ' tem ' + quantidadeLinhas + ' quebras de linha\n';
});
alert(mensagem);
```

O alert que isso dá é:

> A div div1 tem 1 quebras de linha
>   A div div2 tem 6 quebras de linha
>   A div div3 tem 0 quebras de linha

Answer (score 2):

o teste de quebra de linha no Javascript por Regex é \n como o Wakin disse, veja o teste no console do Chrome:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

caso tenha problemas com quebras de linha em versões difeentes de S.O tente isso:

```
var newExpression = expression.replace("\r\n", "\n");
```

Ou simplesmente retirá-las da validação caso não sejam necessárias:

```
var newExpression = expression.replace("\r\n", "");
```

Dica: expressões como \d\d\d\d podem ser simplificados por `[\d]{4}`

Indico este site também para testar suas expressões regulares:
http://regexpal.com/