# Como verificar se um input tem uma String?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Preciso verificar se o usuário digitou uma string em um campo em que só pode receber um Integer, fiz o sequinte código e quando eu clico em no botão, ele me retorna sempre o alert independente de eu escrever um integer ou uma string, oque está errado?

```
$("button.nextButton").unbind("click").click(function(e){ 
  e.preventDefault();

  var endereco = $("#denuncias_end").val();
  if(typeof endereco == 'number') 
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    alert("Por favor, numero de endereco somente em numeros.");
    return false;
  } 
});
```

Comment: Sugestão: Faça um alert após o primeiro que mostre `typeof endereco`.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode verificar com uma expressão regular e o método [match](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp), veja:

```js
$("button.nextButton").unbind("click").click(function(e){ 
  e.preventDefault();

  var endereco = $("#denuncias_end").val();
  
  //if(endereco.match(/^\d+$/)) // retorna um array se verdadeiro ou nulo se falso
  if(/^\d+$/.test(endereco)) // retorna verdadeiro ou falso
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    alert("Por favor, numero de endereco somente em numeros.");
    return false;
  } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="denuncias_end">
    
    <button class="nextButton">Next</button>
```

Para este caso em específico, esta opção é mais viável que o [$.isNumeric](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.isnumeric/), note que:

```
$.isNumeric( "-10" );     // true
$.isNumeric( 16 );        // true
$.isNumeric( 0xFF );      // true
$.isNumeric( "0xFF" );    // true
$.isNumeric( "8e5" );     // true (exponential notation string)
$.isNumeric( 3.1415 );    // true
$.isNumeric( +10 );       // true
$.isNumeric( 0144 );      // true (octal integer literal)
$.isNumeric( "" );        // false
$.isNumeric({});          // false (empty object)
$.isNumeric( NaN );       // false
$.isNumeric( null );      // false
$.isNumeric( true );      // false
$.isNumeric( Infinity );  // false
$.isNumeric( undefined ); // false
```

#### EDITADO

Conforme sugestão do @Qmechanic73 utilizar `.test()` em alternativa ao `.match()` para este caso. [Veja aqui o motivo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17072/detectar-quebra-de-linha/17207#17207)

Comment: Boa resposta! Eu só alteraria o `.match()` por [`.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test), pois você só quer saber se a *string* contem ou não números, eu até cheguei a postar algo sobre isso [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17207/6454).

Comment: @Qmechanic73, você tem razão, neste caso, não há motivos para utilizar `match()` e sim `test()`. Editei adicionando sua sugestão.

Comment: Desse seu jeito funcionou bem como o esperado, testei com strings e integers. Mas quando eu clico em salvar que é o meu botão nextButton, ele aparece o alert com a mensagem, mas permite salvar. Eu mesmo respondi a minha pergunta com o código que fiz, olhe só...

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que `endereco` no seu código sempre será uma `String`, porque `jQuery.val()` sempre vai retornar a `String` para um input ou uma textarea.

Para fazer a verificação que você quer, você precisa usar o `parseInt`, que vai retornar `NaN` se ele não conseguir parsear um inteiro na sua entrada. Você pode usar a função `isNaN` para saber se uma variável é `NaN`. Seu código atualizado ficaria:

```
$("button.nextButton").unbind("click").click(function(e){ 
  e.preventDefault();

  var endereco = parseInt($("#denuncias_end").val());
  if(!isNaN(endereco)) 
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    alert("Por favor, numero de endereco somente em numeros.");
    return false;
  } 
});
```

Como citado [nessa resposta do StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122808/javascript-jquery-validating-numbers-coming-from-val), também se pode usar `jQuery.isNumeric` para definir se uma String é um número.

Comment: Opa, desse seu jeito funcionou aqui também, mas quando eu clico no botão de salvar o meu nextButton ali, ele aparece o alert e permite salvar. Olhe como eu fiz na resposta da pergunta.

Comment: Não entendi o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui fazer do seguinte modo:

Ao pressionar as teclas no *input* ele já verifica se são números ou *strings* conforme a tabela ASCII.

```
$("#denuncias_end").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
       alert("Digite somente Numeros");
       $("#denuncias_end").focus();
       return false;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Faz o seguinte:

```
$(document).on("click", "button.nextButton", function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();

    var endereco = parseInt($("#denuncias_end").val());
    var regex = new RegExp(/^-?\d*\.?\d*$/);
    if(regex.test(endereco)) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Por favor, numero de endereco somente em numeros.");
        return false;
    } 
});
```

Isso deverá funcionar bem.